# Java Code method

Tags: java, class, methods

I am new to Java and would like your help with the following simple and short code:

```
public boolean hasPassed(Student s)
{ 
    return (grade > 45);
}
```

The above, code, is part of a program in Java.

The following is the full code for the simple exemplar program if you would like to know:

```
public class Student  
{   
    private String name;  
    private int grade;  
    public Student(String n)   
    {      
       name = n;   
    }   
    public void setGrade(int g)  
    {   
       grade = g;  
    }   
    public boolean hasPassed(Student s)   
    {   
       return (grade > 45);   
    }   
}
```

#### Question

I believe that this invokes a method called 'hasPassed' to determine whether if student 's' has passed (for example, Computer science).
Could you correct me if I am wrong?

---

Select the best option that describes the function of the `hasPassed` method:

> a) This code defines a method called hasPassed that determines if all students have passed computer science.
>
> b) This code defines a method called hasPassed that determines if student 's' has passed computer science.
>
> c) This code invokes a method called hasPassed to determine if student 's' has passed computer science.
>
> d) This code defines a method called hasPassed that determines if a student has passed computer science.
>
> e) Nothing - this code would not compile.

Since this is a past exam paper question, one of the above is definitely the correct answer. I somehow think it's 'C' but since there are no condition; it doesn't seem possible but then again it does do one of the above and I think it's not 'E' since the function seems correct and compile-able, just lacking a condition is all. Thanks for your time for reading this.

Comment: Nothing's invoking the method yet.  It merely defines a condition in which, if the value of the `grade` variable is greater than 45 for this instance, then it returns `true`.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Are you looking for an explanation of what that method does? I'm not quite sure what you're looking for.

Comment: Also the `grade` it's using to compare to `45` is the current object's `grade` field, not the passed `Student` object's.

Comment: Suggest to you start off with reading about data types, operators, ... (Search for _Java Nuts and Bolts_, it's a free tutorial.)

Comment: would you like to me update the code with the possible answer out of 5 answers so you could point out the correct answer? I think the code invokes only if a condition is specified but there are no conditions yet the answers outlined in the exampler exam paper seems to be according to this as if the condition is defined. it's confusing at the moment.

Comment: Sure... do that I guess

Comment: I have updated the question with the possible answers. I'd appreciate if one of you guys could outline the possible correct answer, thanks :)

Comment: @user3272323 Please read my answer and thank you for making the question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **d)**

> d) This code defines a method called hasPassed that determines if a student has passed computer science.

So let's go over why:

Here are the option:

> a) This code defines a method called hasPassed that determines if all students have passed computer science.
>
> b) This code defines a method called hasPassed that determines if student 's' has passed computer science.
>
> c) This code invokes a method called hasPassed to determine if student 's' has passed computer science.
>
> d) This code defines a method called hasPassed that determines if a student has passed computer science.
>
> e) Nothing - this code would not compile.

Firstly, it would compile.

For **a**: it doesn't determine if *all* students have passed, just one (that specific instance of the class)

For **b**: the method uses `Student s` as a parameter, but doesn't refer to that student at all. `grade` has nothing to do with student 's'

For **c**: this does not *invoke* a method. Invoking a method would be calling a method. Also, the same thing with part **b**, it has nothing to do with student 's'

And that leaves you with **d** which happes to be the correct description of the method.

Comment: This makes things more clear, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Student  
{   
    private String name;  
    private int grade;  
    public Student(String n)   
    {      
       name = n;   
    }   
    public void setGrade(int g)  
    {   
       grade = g;  
    }   
    public boolean hasPassed()   
    {   
       return (grade > 45);   
    }   
} 

//method hasPassed() not needs any param
```

use ex:

```
Student stu = new student("kylin");
    stu.setGrade(100);
    if(stu.hasPassed()){
       System.Out.Println("passed!");
    }
```

Comment: Your code seems perfect but the exam paper only gave us the code that i provided and outlines the possible answers and one of it is definitely correct so i am trying to somehow work out the possible answer according to the basic codes that have been provided. This would be perfect had i been asked to develop the code but unfortunately i can only work with what has been given :)

Comment: Not the question. And you just copied my comment anyways.